# IONIC delete image from gallery

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using [cordova file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/) plugin to delete image from gallery. here is the code

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path+filename, function (result) {
     result.remove(function(data){
            console.log(data)
      });
 });
```

As per above code I am getting success return and file is also deleted from folder. But When I am going to the gallery it is showing me a blank thumbnail. When I am trying to open this file it is showing only grey color. In details it is showing the old path. But in that path file does not exists. I think this is a kind of cache. How can I delete that blank file?

Comment: You should tell the media scanner that you removed the file. Or reboot your device.

Comment: Thanks. I did not heard about Media Scanner before. I have scanned the device and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was ok, all I need to use [Media Scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mediascanner) to scan the gallery.

Comment: Can you please let me know, how you used the above package.